Error configuración beans en un repositorio al usar @Repository
Estoy algo verde con este tema.
Estoy creando un proyecto base en Java con Spring Boot con una estructura "hexagonal". Principalmente tengo un modulo de arranque, otro para los servicios, otro para las implementaciones, además de uno para los repositorios y otro para los controladores.

El fichero de arranque sería este
package com.prueba.kampos.boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.prueba.kampos"})
public class DemoApplication {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
 }
}

La implementación del servicio sería este (con su @Service, la interfaz está en otro módulo)
package com.prueba.kampos.application.user.services;

import com.prueba.kampos.domain.user.repositories.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

 @Autowired
 private UserRepository userRepository;

 @Override
 public void create(UserVO userVO) {
    System.out.printf("2123");
 }
}

Por otro lado tengo el Repositorio de esta manera
package com.prueba.kampos.domain.user.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {}

Y así tendría el controlador
package com.prueba.kampos.infrastructure.goldpass.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.prueba.kampos.applicationapi.user.services.UserService;
import com.prueba.kampos.applicationapi.user.vos.UserVO;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/goldpass")
public class GoldPassController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping("/index")
public String index() {
    UserVO userVO = UserVO.builder().id(1).name("test").password("test").username("test").build();
    this.userService.create(userVO);
    return "index";
}

}
Estas serían las dependencias del modulo de arranque
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.prueba.kampos</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.prueba.kampos</groupId>
        <artifactId>infrastructure</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.prueba.kampos</groupId>
        <artifactId>application</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

El problema es el siguiente
Field userRepository in com.prueba.kampos.application.user.services.UserServiceImpl required 
a bean of type 'com.prueba.kampos.domain.user.repositories.UserRepository' that could not be 
found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.prueba.kampos.domain.user.repositories.UserRepository' 
in your configuration.

Cuando se definen los beans de la clase UserServiceImpl, no encuentra ninguno definido para el repositorio, no se que podría ser, he estado jugando moviendo las dependencias entre módulos y no he encontrado nada. No se porque para la clase service si me ha creado el bean, pero para el repositorio, no.
Si alguien sabe porque podría ser se lo agradecería, aunque puede ser que no haya proporcionado la información suficiente, podría compartir el repositorio si hiciese falta.
Gracias de antemano.

¿y si pasas la inyección de campo a inyección por constructor? Porque creo que no necesitas una interfaz para tu servicio y si hay un error en su creación mejor que te lo diga antes de iniciar la aplicación ¿no crees?

Pero es buena práctica tener que pasar el repositorio que corresponde con ese servicio por el controlador? Entonces desde la capa controlador tenemos que pasarle una instancia del repositorio o cada vez que queramos usar ese servicio, ademas ya no tendría sentido que separe el proyecto en modulos, perdería la arquitectura hexagonal

y que crees que estás haciendo al poner autowired? también pasarle el servicio por el controlador, y que crees que hace el spring IoC container? pasarle una instancia.... inténtalo tal vez así sea más claro tu error y cuando lo corrijas lo puedes regresar, porque sin un [mcve] no hay como ayudarte

No sé si esto es parte de tus pruebas, pero el paquete que sale en el mensaje de error no se corresponde con el que has puesto: com.prueba.domain.user.repositories.UserRepository. Si el paquete que has puesto en el component scan es com.prueba.kampos, es normal que no se haya creado la instancia de ese repositorio

Buenas RubioRic, ha sido fallo al copiar las clases, quise renombrar los paquetes en el texto y han quedado incoherentes, en principio el paquete es el mismo. Lo corrijo en la descripción. Lo siento mucho, gracias

Porque no solo un archivo pom para toda la aplicación? dentro de una carpeta src debería esta toda tu aplicación por que el src es la raiz, veo que tienes modulos externos
